# Can I extend the interface of a contract without redeploying it?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, interfaces

The case I'm dealing with is a contract which should serve as a Data Abstraction Layer.

So ideally, it should provide only getter functions and setter functions.

For example, my interface is:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

interface IDataAbstractionLayer {
    function getX(uint key) external view returns (uint);
    function getY(uint key) external view returns (uint);
    function getZ(uint key) external view returns (uint);
}
```

And my contract is:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

import "./IDataAbstractionLayer.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract DataAbstractionLayer is IDataAbstractionLayer, Ownable {
    struct Record {
        uint256 x;
        uint256 y;
        uint256 z;
    }

    mapping(address => Record) public records;

    function getX(uint key) external view returns (uint) {return records[key].x;}
    function getY(uint key) external view returns (uint) {return records[key].y;}
    function getZ(uint key) external view returns (uint) {return records[key].z;}

    function set(uint key, uint x, uint y, uint z) external onlyOwner {
        records[key] = Record({x: x, y: y, z: z});
    }
}
```

The other contracts in my system know this contract only by its interface (i.e., they interact with it only in order to obtain an attribute of a record).

However, since the Solidity compiler adds an implicit getter function for each public variable, this contract also implements the following function:

```
function records(uint key) external view returns (uint, uint, uint) {
    return (records[key].x, records[key].y, records[key].z);}
```

So I'm wondering - in the future, if I ever decide that I want to implement and deploy a contract which calls this function, will I be able to simply declare it in the `IDataAbstractionLayer` interface and then use it in that contract (which will of course know the address of the (already-deployed) `DataAbstractionLayer` contract)?

Thank you!